# Ionic 4 IOS deeplinks redirect to broswer instead of the actual app

Tags: ios, typescript, cordova, ionic4, deeplink

i am trying to set up deeplinks for my ionic 4 ios app, i followed these steps to accomplish the given task:

- i uploaded an apple site association file to the web version of the app, i used the actual bundle id and app id prefix from Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles page on apple.com
- i verified the website url using https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator, i got 5/5 green results
- i also enabled associated domains in both xcode and on apple.com dev space for the application
- inside the code in the app components i used the following code :

  ```
    const subDeepLinks = this.deeplinks.route({
       '/verify/:code': VerifyPage,
       '/reset-password/:token': ResetPasswordPage,
     }).subscribe((match: any) => {
         this.zone.run(() => this.router.navigate([match.$link.path]));
       }
     });
  ```

And here is the list of the deeplink variables from package.json

```
    "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": {
        "URL_SCHEME": "<my-domain-name>",
        "DEEPLINK_SCHEME": "https",
        "DEEPLINK_HOST": "<my-domain-name>" 
     }
```

I test this using iPhone simulator, i created a contact with a url that is supposed to lead to the app. But when i click on it i get redirected to the web version of the app.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well, it turned out aasa worked. i used my gf's iphone installed the app and checked. so nevermind